# Displaying multilanguage characters in pdf through itext(java)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am facing problem with displaying the chinese , russian etc local languages characters.It is showing blank there.Using the itext. Is there a some standard encoding and font which after converting every character into unicode hexadecimal will take care.

Answer (score 2):

Make your pdf encoding to `UTF-8` use font that supports unicode, 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109392/using-unicode-charater-in-generated-pdf-java-itext) is similar Question

```
  BaseFont unicode =
                BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

**Also see:**

- [Example with code](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=158)

Comment: how to do that, I am struggling with getting the right font and encoding for that?    document.add(new Paragraph(" greecexxx \u039d\u03cd\u03c6\u03b5\u03c2 \u0041 \u6fb3\u95e8\u53f0 \u1A00 \u0042 \u1A00 \u039f\u03a0 ", new Font(bf, 12)));  what bf should be taken in this code to gat the right values printed in pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FontSelector. You can add multiple fonts and it will process your text and use the different fonts where appropriate.

```
 FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
    selector.addFont(FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12));
    selector.addFont(FontFactory.getFont("MSung-Light",
        "UniCNS-UCS2-H", BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED));
    Phrase ph = selector.process(TEXT);
    document.add(new Paragraph(ph));
```

from http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=214